# Bootstrap carousel doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I have implemented a simple carousel but it is not functioning properly. It is stuck on first image and next and previous button is also not working. I have read this code multiple times but I can't figure out the problem. Any help will be appreciated

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.4/tiny-slider.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" width="100%" height="550" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" width="100%" height="550" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" width="100%" height="550" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.2/min/tiny-slider.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: What's in your script.js ?

Comment: Errors in your console?

Answer (score 1):

I think you used the 4.0 version of the carousel with bootstrap 5.1. Try this, it's basically copy and paste from the guide plus minor tweaks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.4/tiny-slider.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img
            src="https://picsum.photos/300
          "
            class="d-block w-100"
            alt="..."
          />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img
            src="https://picsum.photos/400
          "
            class="d-block w-100"
            alt="..."
          />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img
            src="https://picsum.photos/500
          "
            class="d-block w-100"
            alt="..."
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.2/min/tiny-slider.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="script.js"></script>-->
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
</html>
```

Look here for more: [Bootstrap 5.1 Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/)

I used different size of picsum photo to get 3 different images (because it fetches 3 different get requests)

Comment: To clarify, you're missing `-bs` in your data attribute names.

Comment: Thanks i didn't checked the version

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your file and I found out that you are using wrong links of slider and bootstrap. That's why, your carousel was not working fine. But now, It is working absolutely fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <title>Bootstrap Carousel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- The slideshow -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1714208/pexels-photo-1714208.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"
            width="100%"
            height="550"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4050387/pexels-photo-4050387.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"
            width="100%"
            height="550"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3064079/pexels-photo-3064079.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"
            width="100%"
            height="550"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems like a backward solution. If Bootstrap 5 was intended, it's the _markup_ that should be changed, not the library (especially since your change requires jQuery). Also, you'd load 4.6, not 4.0, which is very old.