# why is my image carousel not working on bootstrap 5?

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-5

Please i need help with image carousel on bootstrap 5!!!
Its not working and im very lost.
Also added the data-bs-target for bootstrap 5, that still didnt work
code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="carimages" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carimage" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carimage" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carimage" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active"><img src="slide 1.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <div class="carousel-item active"><img src="slide 2.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <div class="carousel-item active"><img src="slide 3.jpg" alt=""></div>
            </div> 
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carimages" data-slide="prev"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carimages" data-slide="next"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap carousel doesn't seem to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70247292/bootstrap-carousel-doesnt-seem-to-be-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things to consider:

- follow Bootstrap carousel HTML structure as shown in the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#with-indicators),
- use `data-bs-target`, `data-bs-slide-to`, `data-bs-slide` if you use Bootstrap 5 and
- include [Bootstrap JS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start) only once (Bootstrap JS bundle **or** Popper & Bootstrap JS separately, not both).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="carimages" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-bs-target="#carimages" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#carimages" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#carimages" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active"><img src="slide 1.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="carousel-item"><img src="slide 2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="carousel-item"><img src="slide 3.jpg" alt=""></div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carimages" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carimages" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="carimages" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1427830574887-32e5702033b0" class="d-block w-100" alt="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1427830574887-32e5702033b0">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1427830574887-32e5702033b0" class="d-block w-100" alt="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1427830574887-32e5702033b0">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1427830574887-32e5702033b0" class="d-block w-100" alt="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1427830574887-32e5702033b0">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </a>
                
              </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Some explanation is expected rather than just a code dump. See [answer].